# How to use SQL IN statement with list of Items selected from treeviewlist?

Tags: vb.net

How can I join the `accid` string values from the *For Next* loop (below) into one single string?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim accid As String
        Dim iLast As Integer
        iLast = trv.Nodes.Count
        Dim p As Integer = 0
        For p = 0 To iLast - 1
            If TrV.Nodes(p).Checked = True Then
                accid = Strings.Left(TrV.Nodes(p).Text, 9)
                MsgBox(accid)
            End If
        Next
 End Sub
```

This gives me a separate output of string `"accid"`
I want this output: `"accid1,accid2,accid3"`

Thanks for supporting!

Comment: If you're going to use that string for an `IN` clause in  SQL Server, you should really create a List(Of String) of the values and use that for a table-valued parameter: [Using Table-Valued Parameters
in SQL Server and .NET](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html). It may look like a lot to read, but it explains it clearly.

Comment: I will look into this table valued parameters.. glad some one point me to the right direction because the method i,m following is like taking a taxi instead of an uber drive :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build your string inside the loop, and then do the MsgBox outside the loop.  Something like this should work:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim accid As String
        Dim iLast As Integer
        iLast = trv.Nodes.Count
        Dim p As Integer = 0

        For p = 0 To iLast - 1
            If TrV.Nodes(p).Checked = True Then
                accid = accid & Strings.Left(TrV.Nodes(p).Text, 9) & ","  'notice the change here
            End If
        Next

        accid = accid.Remove(accid.Length - 1, 1)
        MsgBox(accid)
 End Sub
```

Comment: this perfectly sums up my problem. because i was trying to retrieve those values by means of For Next Loop

Comment: @HasanAnjum If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with very few lines of code using Linq and String.Join.

```
Dim texts = TrV.Nodes.Cast(Of TreeNode)().
                Where(Function(n) n.Checked).
                Select(Function(c) Strings.Left(c.Text,9))
Dim result = String.Join(",", texts)
```

Comment: this works perfectly. i did not use function in treeview nodes before. bravo